# qemu-system-arm problems adding second NIC/bridge

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, qemu, arm, bridge

I am running Qemu under a host with two bridge interfaces and would simply like to bridge them to guest NICs. All of this works fine when bridging one NIC either by creating a bridge manually or using qemu-bridge-helper such as:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -smp 4 -m 1024 -kernel kernel/linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage -append 'root=/dev/ram rootfstype=ramfs rdinit=/sbin/init console=ttyAMA0 noswap rw loglevel=3' -sd ramdisk/qemu -nographic -redir tcp:2200::22 -net nic -net bridge,br=br0
```

However simply adding another *-net nic -net bridge,br=1* yields following, and only the first NIC is seen by guest:

```
Warning: hub port hub0port2 has no peer 
Warning: netdev hub0port2 has no peer 
Warning: requested NIC (anonymous, model unspecified) was not created (not supported by this machine?)
```

I've tried different variations and perhaps the farthest I could go was probably using this invocation:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -smp 4 -m 1024 -kernel kernel/linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage -append 'root=/dev/ram rootfstype=ramfs rdinit=/sbin/init console=ttyAMA0 noswap rw loglevel=3' -sd ramdisk/qemu -nographic -redir tcp:2200::22 -net nic,netdev=hn0,vlan=0 -netdev bridge,br=br0,id=hn0 -net nic,netdev=hn1 -netdev bridge,br=br1,id=hn1
```

Which only gives warning about missing peer, anyway the issue of having only one NIC remains:

```
Warning: netdev hn1 has no peer
Warning: requested NIC (anonymous, model unspecified) was not created (not supported by this machine?)
```

I've tried adding and playing around with *vlan=* parameters but that didn't help either. Is there anything I'm clearly missing?

Note that I'm running qemu inside LXC, even though I've tried on another Debian machine and got the same warnings.

Qemu version:

```
root@trusty64:/share/appliance# qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```